# Forced to use using 2-Step Authentication to keep online profiles safe?

Tags: passwords, authentication, attacks, attack-prevention

I am starting to see a majority of services, websites, and social networks offering the 2-step Authentication like crazy now to protect their users. Also, after reading how the Twitter Account N was hacked, 2-Step Authentication to protect our accounts online seems like a requirement more and more.

There is even a website to help see which services uses it and doesn't use it at [Two Factor Auth (2FA)](http://twofactorauth.org/).

I have had several major hacking attempts all over my social networking profiles, and own personal websites which I administrate and help run.

I also feel like we have to use it, or else we will have our banking accounts accessed and comprised.

With my last month experiences, I had 107 loggin attempts text messaged to me from my PayPal and Facebook account. They all failed, but if it wasn't for the login code texted to my phone, I would of had money taken out of my account.

Are we now forced to use 2-Step Authentication to keep our accounts and assets secure now? Should we make this a web standard to make sure people are secure to just visit our websites and services?

Answer (score 1):

Forced? No. But passwords alone have known weakness. Using 2-factor methods help to mitigate the risks of those weaknesses.

That also means that we can't make it a web standard for every login, because there are instances where it does not make sense in terms of mitigating those risks.

I suspect that the current 2-factor is a stepping stone to better things. Biometrics and physical tokens can be combined to provide something similar to 2-factor and people are working on making that accessible for the masses.

Comment: Very true, my friend. For me, it is the only thing right now, besides for my long complex passwords, that is keeping people out of my accounts and services.

Answer (score 0):

Well nobody is forcing us,but yeah it's comparatively secure than other authentication schemes. And since two-factor authentication is relatively new to the web (talking in a sense that number of exploits are very less) so I think we should give it some time to make sure that it fulfil our security concerns of safe internet usage.

P.S I am not an Englishman